# Выполнение команд на удаленном терминале по нажатию кнопок на сайте

Tags: java, python, веб-программирование

Имеется готовая java-программа. Хочу создать веб-сервис с несколькими полями и кнопками, который по нажатию этих кнопок будет обрабатывать данные из форм и передавать на выполнение в args на удаленный сервер в командную строку. Подскажите, с помощью каких инструментов это лучше реализовать? 
Не имею опыта в php, только java и python.
Или, может, такой подход слишком избыточен?

Comment: Предлагаю подумать над заголовком, так как Ваш вариант не отражает суть вопроса. Как я понимаю, Вы хотите по нажатию кнопок на сайте выполнять команды в терминале на удаленном сервере?

Comment: Да, именно так, это возможно?
Согласен, заголовок не совсем удачный

Comment: У готовый программы нет `API`?

Comment: Почему же на терминале? Если есть Java код, зачем взаимодействовать с ним через терминал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача разбивается на 2 задачи:

- Перехватить событие на удаленном сервере. Можно на удаленном сервере создать проект на `pyhon` при помощи микрофреймворка [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/):

  ```
  from flask import Flask
  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route("/")
  def hello():
      // Запуск Java-программы

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      app.run()
  ```
- Запустить `Java` программу из `python` через терминал. Для этого можно использовать метод `getoutput` из библиотеки [commands](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html):

  ```
  java -classpath . /path/to/java/app
  ```

Но на вашем месте я бы доделал саму программу на `Java` для взаимодествия через `WEB`, так как мое решение является костылем.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!
Первая задача решает мою проблему. Со временем обязательно допилю программу на Java.
Ещё раз спасибо!